# Are thieves at a disadvantage when it comes to dragon fights?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Fighting a dragon, at least in the videos, looks to be combat focused (as it should be) so armor, weapon skill, and magic skill all aid in killing a dragon.  My question is, would a thief-type character (or a non-destruction mage) still be able to kill a dragon?

Comment: I can't give any definite answer since I haven't gotten to play yet, but it seems like you could use Alchemy to make some poison and go for poison + bow and arrows. Plus, I do remember one of the developer things I read talking about how they want everyone to be able to kill at least one dragon, so it should scale appropriately [citation needed].

Comment: Has anybody ever had trouble killing a dragon?

Comment: @WilliamMioch I did, on master difficulty without any magic/elemental defense enchantments.

Comment: Fighting a dragon is like fighting a mage. Magic resist rules. If you don't have that, then fire resist potions or enchants. Or failing all, use the Bow of Ungodly Damage, I guess. Just made that up, by the way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm a Thief with a bow... Archer Thief. I have no real issues, just have to have good cover nearby!

Comment: Also, I tended to lure Dragons near guards when I was low level - helps.

Comment: Yes, I am now many hours into the game, and Archer Thief is absolutely viable.  I do need to find cover, or rely on my companion/nearby guards, but I am by no means unable to kill (or even solo) a dragon.  So those of you out there, sneak around all you like, you'll still get your precious Dragon Souls =)

Comment: dagger thieves, on the other hand, ARE at a disadvantage though, until the dragon is dumb enough to land, that is

Comment: I second @yx!!!

Comment: I was playing an Archer Thief who relies heavily on alchemy, when I encountered a dragon in the middle of a swampy area with no trees. With my poisons, potions, and frost bow, I was able to bring down the dragon with little difficulty. My only complaint is that my paralysis potion did not paralyze the flying dragon.

Comment: I'm playing an archery thief. It takes a lot of arrows to kill a dragon, but you'd be surprised how well a tree protects you from a dragon's frost breath. Getting the melee sneak attack is challenging even with high Sneak, as they don't land for long, can spot you well, and when they sleep it tends to be atop word walls you can't reach in melee.

Answer (score 5):

Earlier on you'll have to be a total wimp and kite the dragon around, plinking at it from cover with your bow. Be sure to keep lots of ammo.

Later on, I'm currently level 25 and I've assassinated a couple of slumbering dragons with one well placed backstab(with a dagger, of course). Just make sure your Sneak and 1-hander skill is solid if you wanna try that though.

Answer (score 4):

There is a Thu'um that pulls dragons out of the air. Get that.

Comment: Part of the main quest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a dagger type thief, just let the dragon fly away, then move to his direction. Usually he will be standing on a dragon wall, so just sneak behind him and attack him... This can grant you a one hit kill sometimes if you have the Assassin's Blade perk, a good dagger and the Dark Brotherhood gloves...

Answer (score 1):

Conjure a flame atronarch and let her fireball it while you safely barrage the dragon with poisoned arrows and use potion to boost your archery damage. Invisible spell is truly handy if you're alone. Be patient. Keep attacking, stay alive and you'll eventually own it. I'm an assassin/thief, using sneak style archery and one handed for quick and powerful battling. I'm a Khajit.

Answer (score 1):

You can get one hit kills as an assassin if you leave your left hand empty and have a good dagger in the right hand, as well as the shadow warrior perk.  (need the assassins blade perk too, duh!)

Walk up to the landed dragon, when you are close, go to stealth and immediately stab.  You will at least get the 15x or 30x (if you have the shrouded gloves) and often go into a mini-sequence of brutally stabbing it in the head.  If you just get the 15x damage, unstealth, restealth and stab immediately again.  usually by the 3rd shot you will be on the dragons back stabbing it in the brain.

Oh, and if you do this at the right time when a bear is attacking you, I have seen an animation where you thrust your arm down its throat and the twist your arm for an instant kill.

Funny to do on slaughterfish hehe, all this crazy animation and what not for just killing a fish :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're a thief I would imagine sneaking is your best bet.  Dual wielding and bows would be a close second.  Use your strengths, alchemy will be your friend.  Poisons will definitely tip the fight in your favor.